# Where is the variable being stored during a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Ok, I understand that in the code below a closure is created when the parent function counter returns an object with a method called count. But can somebody clarify if I'm understanding the control flow correctly? After the counter function is assigned to variable `c` the first time the method it is invoked, by `c.count()`, the output is 1. And each additional time it is called the stored `n` is incremented and the new value is returned. I understand this is possible through the magic of closure so that by calling this four times I get a new value each time ending with 4 instead of simply getting 1 four times over. But where is the value that `n` holds each time "hanging out" while it waits for me to call the count method again to increment the most recently created value? What will it take for `n` to have a clean slate again as 0? If I declare a new variable and assign the function `counter` to it? Trying to wrap my head around all this and these questions occurred to me. I'm not sure if what I'm asking is obnoxious or painfully obvious-- thank you in advance.

```
function counter() {
    var n = 0;
    return {
        count: function() { return ++n; },
    };
}
var c = counter();
console.log(c.count()); // 1
console.log(c.count()); // 2
console.log(c.count()); // 3
console.log(c.count()); // 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where is the value that n holds each time "hanging out" while it waits for me to call the count method again to increment the most recently created value?

Variable `n`, of course, is hold in memory. Its behavior is just like on global scope, but within the `counter` scope.

> What will it take for n to have a clean slate again as 0?

Reset it.

I've rewritten your example in self-executing function style to make it clearer. Hope it helps.

```
var c = (function counter(){
    var n = 0;
    return {
        count: function() { return ++n; },
        //don't use keyword 'var', it will create a new variable instead of reseting n
        reset: function() { n = 0},
    };
})();
console.log(c.count()); // 1
console.log(c.count()); // 2
console.log(c.count()); // 3
console.log(c.count()); // 4
console.log(c.reset());
console.log(c.count()); // 1
console.log(c.count()); // 2
console.log(c.count()); // 3
console.log(c.count()); // 4
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing I still wonder about though when I asked about declaring a new variable to store a new copy of `counter` to "reset" n, ex. such as `var d = counter();` and then `console.log(d.count());` starts the `count` back at 1 without a specific `reset` method to reset it. Is this so because this new `counter` is completely separate from the `counter` stored in `c`?

Comment: @phizzy Yes. That's closure all about. Two cents look completely the same, but they're still two different cents.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in a closure are not stored on any object available from within JavaScript itself, so it is impossible to reset it unless you add another function for it in the object you return:

```
function counter() {
    var n = 0;
    return {
        count: function() { return ++n; },
        reset: function() { n = 0; }
    };
}
```